# Evaluate a limit in two variables - interesting limit

Tags: calculus

Fix $a \in (0,1]$. I am trying to compute the following limit :

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}    \frac{|x \ln(x)- y \ln(y)|}{|x^{1+a} - y^{1+a}|}$$

and

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (p,p)}    \frac{|x \ln(x)- y \ln(y)|}{|x^{1+a} - y^{1+a}|}$$

with $p \neq 0.$

I have no idea to how to start. Someone could give me a help?

thanks in advance

Comment: For the first one, along any line $y=mx$ the limit is $-\infty$, as l'Hopital's rule can show. So maybe that's the limit in general at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $u(t)=t\ln(t)$ and $v(t)=t^{1+a}$ then both functions are $C^1$ on $(0,\infty)$ and for every $x<y$ Cauchy's mean value theorem gives a $c\in (x,y)$ such that 
$$
\frac{u(x)-u(y)}{v(x)-v(y)}=\frac{u'(c)}{v'(c)} = \frac{1+\ln(c)}{(1+a)c^a}\to -\infty \quad \text{ as } x<y\to 0 .
$$
Therefore the first limit is $\infty$.

If $p>0$ then $u$, $v$ are $C^1$ in a neighborhood of $p$ and therefore, passing to the limit as $c\to p$ in the above expression we get that the limit is $|u'(p)/v'(p)|$.